# Select from table where jsonb array has elements with specific properties

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

How can I select the rows in a table having a jsonb array that has elements with a specific property ?

Eg: If the jsonb is the following

```
{ "list" : [
     {"name": "John", "money": 100},  
     {"name": "Dan", "money": 900}
  ]
}
```

How can I select the rows having at least one element with name 'Dan' in the array ? 
I tried with:

```
select jsonb_pretty(data) from table where data -> 'list' @>  '{"name": "Dan"}';
```

but id does not return any rows.

Comment: what is your excepted value? the whole row or just {"name": "Dan", "money": 900} ?

Comment: `SELECT jsonb_pretty(data) FROM table WHERE data -> 'list' @> '[{"name": "Dan"}]'` ?

Comment: @FeanDoe Doesn't matter, I just want to be able to identify that row.

Comment: @bma Seems like this one works! Would you like to write an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key here is that the JSONB value (in the column) needs to match the filter:

```
SELECT jsonb_pretty(data)
FROM table
WHERE data -> 'list' @> '[{"name": "Dan"}]'
```

Note the `[]` around `[{"name": "Dan"}]` filter.

PostgreSQL JSON/JSONB Functions and Operators [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html) for further reference.